# Image control point skewing

Tags: ios, catransform3d, cgaffinetransformscale

ers,

I have a requirement for a image skewing control, whose behaviour's demonstrated by the two following screenshots:

[image: Starting state]

and

[image: Control point moved]

The control point drawing and user interactions are "easy" and are mostly done. Basically, as you most likely already understand, the control points can be moved around, one at a time, to distort and skew the image.

What I'm having a problem with is the actual image transformation created from the different user interactions. Meaning - I have no clue how to map the user interactions to a image transformation. Which part of the skew transform should be modified with which combination of control points or control points alone?

Quite confusing I might add. I've read up quite a few of the resources online about Skew transforms and that's all fine and dandy, but I really don't see a way to apply this via the control points.

Any and all tips are welcome!

Comment: see https://github.com/agens-no/AGGeometryKit

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.